# BitBucket & Bamboo - check pull request doesn't break build on destination branch

Tags: continuous-integration, bitbucket, bamboo

I currently have my BitBucket set up to follow the Git flow model (https://datasift.github.io/gitflow/IntroducingGitFlow.html) and have my Bamboo CI running against the `develop` branch.

What I want to know is if I can set up BitBucket to only approve and/or merge a pull request from a feature branch if that merge would not break the build on the `develop` branch.

So if we have a pull request to merge branch `feature/amazing-new/feature` the pull request will only be closed and the branch merged in to `develop` if Bamboo can do the merge and build successfully.

I've had a look around and only seen answers that refer to build plans that run against the feature branch itself and the BitBucket docs only have paragraph covering builds and pull requests: https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/checks-for-merging-pull-requests-776640039.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bamboo can be configured to build merge result: https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamboo/using-plan-branches-289276872.html#Usingplanbranches-Branchupdater

When new commit in feature branch detected it will merge feature branch to master in working copy, build and send result to Bitbucket. At Bitbucket side you can configure pull request settings to not allow PR merge if there're broken builds.